# Many-Many relationship in EF6 with other colums in mapper class

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have existing tables including the mapper table. I have to set the Entity Framework annotations. I am confused about how to achieve that. there are three tables,

1. Model (ModelId, ModelName),
2. Department (DepartmentId, DepartmentName)
3. ModelDepartmentMapper (ModelDepartmentMapperId, ModelId, DepartmentId, ModelStatus)

I have created the classes as:

```
public class Model
{
    public int ModelId { get; private set; }
    public string ModelName { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; private set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; private set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Model> Models { get; private set; }
}

public class JoinModelDepartment
{
    public int JoinModelDepartmentId { get; private set; }
    public Guid ModelId { get; private set; }
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; private set; }
    public int ModelStatus { get; private set; }
}
```

And in DBContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>()
        .HasMany<Department>(s => s.Departments)
        .WithMany(c => c.Models)
        .Map(cs =>
        {
            cs.MapLeftKey("ModelGuid");
            cs.MapRightKey("DepartmentGuid");
            cs.ToTable("JoinModelDepartment");
        });
}
```

Please guide me how to add **ModelStatus** in the mapper table. Do I need to create it manually or there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What I would tend to do is move these kinds of mappings into their own class files. Theres a brilliant tutorial found here:

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/move-configurations-to-seperate-class-in-code-first.aspx

This lets you map out each of the tables individually and it will build the database off of them.

So in your case you would have a Model, Department and a ModelDepartmentMapper class file. From there you can set all the relevant columns and how they are linked to another table as well as column types IE VARCHAR etc